# Spring Read value from properties file into @SpringBootApplication class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I've a SpringBootApplication and I want read a value from my property file.

My @SpringBootApplication class is this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.test")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application {
      private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

      @Value("${server.modem.delay}")
      private int modemSmsDelay;

     @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
     @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
     public Service smsService() {      
         settings();
         Service service = Service.getInstance();       
         return service;
     }
      private void settings() {     
           log.debug("Delay per invio sms " + modemSmsDelay +"ms");     
            Settings.gatewayDispatcherYield = modemSmsDelay;
     }
}
```

Unfortunately in in method called "settings" the value of property modemSmsDelay is 0 also if in my application.properties file it's 1000.

In other parts of my app I can read values without problems.

==== UPDATE =====

I solved the problem. Infact my code works, is not needed @PostConstruct to make @Value tag work, also if it's desiderable in several circustances.
I had a problem in my Spring configuration that prevented the execution of all annotation as @PostConstruct,@Autowire, etc.
I noticed this from log where Spring printed a Warning message.

Comment: You do not need to add ComponentScan or PropertySource annotations, as the SpringBootApplication annotation already includes them.

Comment: check if the path of `application.properties` is correct and you're passing correct property name `server.modem.delay`

Comment: He's calling it from the constructor.

Comment: I see. The answer below is correct, he will need to add the PostConstruct annotation.

Comment: @11thdimention The path of application.properties it's fine and also the property name.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the @PostConstruct annotation on your settings() method rather than calling it from the constructor.  This will cause the method to be called automagically after the constructor exits.

Comment: Also if I annotate settings() method with @PostConstruct annotation, the method is not called.

Comment: Just to puntualize, I'm not calling settings() from constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

**@Resource private Environment environment;**

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import my.beautiful.code.SomeClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Resource
  private Environment environment;

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  @Bean(name = "someClient")
  public SomeClient loadSomeClient() {
      SomeClient bean = new SomeClient();
      ...
      bean.setHeaderContentType(environment.getProperty("contentType"));
      bean.setRestUrl(environment.getProperty("rest.url"));   
      ...
      return bean;
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

And in my application.properties

```
contentType=some_value
rest.url=http://localhost/....
```

HTH